# Requests to MS Graph API gives me "Authorization Request Denied - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"

Tags: ios, node.js, azure, active-directory, azure-mobile-services

I have a question about "Authorization Request Denied - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" message that I keep getting back from my requests to Windows Graph API.

Specifically, I'm working in Azure cloud. I have an iOS mobile app that invokes an API.
I have turned on "Authentication for Active Directory" in my Portal.

Then, on the client side (iOS):

```
[self.todoService.client loginWithProvider:@"windowsazureactivedirectory"
                                controller:self
                                  animated:YES
                                completion:^(MSUser *user, NSError *error) {

                                    if(!error && user) {
                                        [self refresh];

                                    } 
                                }]; //loginWithProvider
```

So returns a valid MSUser object. I see the web login controller appear, I sign in with my un/pw, and then it lets me access my Easy Table's data...etc.

Now, I want to invoke an Easy API that I've created in Azure called **getUserData**. Hence, I simply insert the invokeAPI code like this (iOS):

```
[self.todoService.client loginWithProvider:@"windowsazureactivedirectory"
                                controller:self
                                  animated:YES
                                completion:^(MSUser *user, NSError *error) {

                                    if(!error && user) {

                                        //NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                                        //[dict setObject:@YES forKey:@"complete"];

                                        NSLog(@"%s - %@", __FUNCTION__, user);
                                        [self refresh];

                                        [self.todoService.client invokeAPI:@"getUserData"
                                                                      body:nil
                                                                HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                                                parameters:nil
                                                                   headers:nil
                                                                completion:^(id  _Nullable result, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                                    NSLog(@"%s - API returned response! ", __FUNCTION__);
                                                                    NSLog(@"%@", result); //TODO: user info here!! :D

                                                                }]; //invokAPI

                                    } //if user returned from AAD login is valid

                                }]; //loginWithProvider
```

Everything is fine as the API is called and I can see the response data.

On the server side (Node JS), I basically do 3 things:

1st is to get the user object id from the request object:

```
req.azureMobile.user.getIdentity().then((data) => {
   //get user object ID
}
```

2nd, make a request to **https://login.windows.net** to get an Access Token with a username/password.

```
var options = {
    url: "https://login.windows.net/" + tenant_domain + "/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0",
    method: 'POST',
    form: {
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        resource: "https://graph.windows.net",
        client_id: clientID,
        client_secret: key
    }
};

req(options, function (err, resp, body) {
    //get the result back
}
```

I get a whole bunch of data back including the Access Token.

3rd, make a request to https://graph.windows.net/, and provide this Access Token along with my User Object ID:

```
var options = {
    url: "https://graph.windows.net/" + tenant_domain + "/users/" + objectId + "?api-version=1.0",
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    }
};
```

This is so that I can **User data**. Now, in a separate test Subscription, I set up all the basic read permissions for AAD and Graph in my AAD management. I successfully get the user's full data back like so:

```
user =     {
    accountEnabled = 1;
    assignedLicenses =         (
    );
    assignedPlans =         (
    );
    city = xxxxxxxxx;
    country = xxxxxxxxxx;
    department = Dev;
    dirSyncEnabled = "<null>";
    displayName = xxxxxx;
    facsimileTelephoneNumber = "<null>";
    givenName = hehe;
    jobTitle = "iOS dev";
    lastDirSyncTime = "<null>";
    mail = "<null>";
    mailNickname = "xxxxxxxxxx.com#EXT#";
    mobile = "+xx xxx xxxx 3852";
    objectId = "xxxxxxx-2c70-4aab-b261-3b2b97dc5c50";
    objectType = User;
    "odata.metadata" = "https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.User/@Element";
    "odata.type" = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.User";
    otherMails =         (
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
    );
...etc
}
```

However, in another subscription, I did the exact same steps. Even going as far as checking all the permissions like so:

[image]

I keep getting an "Authorization Request Denied,  Insufficient privileges" message. The error is null so I know everything else went through correctly.

I can't figure out why because everything processes through and I checked all of my AAD and Graph permissions.

log result:

-----body------

### '{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}'

Thanks for any help, and appreciate everyone's time

Comment: Normally I have seen this error when the user account gets added as a `Guest` instead of a `Member`. Can you check if that's the case here with this particular Azure AD? You would need to use Azure AD PowerShell Cmdlets for that.

Comment: ok, I'll check if the un/pw I used to sign in for this particular Azure AD is a Guest or Member when Monday rolls around and update you.

Comment: hi Gaurav, in order to get the permissions working for the apps, you must be a global admin. I tried it with 3 different types: billing admin, service admin, User. None of which works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to upgrade the role of the AD application you use to a administrator permission. Run the following commands in `PowerShell`:

```
Connect-MsolService
$ClientIdWebApp = '{your_AD_application_client_id}'
$webApp = Get-MsolServicePrincipal –AppPrincipalId $ClientIdWebApp
#use Add-MsolRoleMember to add it to "Company Administrator" role).
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleName "Company Administrator" -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleMemberObjectId $webApp.ObjectId
```

Comment: hi Gary, so after some time, it turns out that we needed a "Global Admin" to go through those steps. Then, when we ran the app, we can successfully query the Graph API, and get User data. Hence, it was the admin permissions after all.